# Using nested include on an array

Tags: chai

I am trying to verify that an array has 2 elements with the following values:

```
expect([{
        createdAt: 1545588925941,
        updatedAt: 1545588925941,
        id: '5c1fd0bdd38b1b2bb0875dd9',
        readAt: null,
        type: 'ResidentCreatedTask',
        dataVersion: 0,
        data: '{}',
        user: '5c1fd0bdd38b1b2bb0875dd6',
        home: '5c1fd0bdd38b1b2bb0875dd8'
    },
    {
        createdAt: 1545588925941,
        updatedAt: 1545588925941,
        id: '5c1fd0bdd38b1b2bb0875dd9',
        readAt: null,
        type: 'ResidentCreatedTask',
        dataVersion: 0,
        data: '{}',
        user: '5c1fd0bdd38b1b2bb0875dd6',
        home: '5c1fd0bdd38b1b2bb0875dd8'
    }
]).to.be.an('array').that.has.lengthOf(2).and.to.deep.nested.include({
    0: {
        type: 'ResidentCreatedTask'
    },
    1: {
        type: 'ResidentCreatedTask'
    },
});
```

But it's not working. I also tried changing the keys to strings with brackets like `'[0]'` and `'[1]'`.

I also tried removing the keys and making the val of includes an array like this:

```
.include([{ type: 'ResidentCreatedTask' }, { type: 'ResidentCreatedTask' }]);
```

But this also didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't like this solution, but you can wrap it an object.

So our payload is `const payload = [{ id: 0 },{ id: 1 }]`. Doing the following will not work, this is what I did in original post:

```
expect(payload).to.nested.include({ '[0].id': 0, '[1].id': 1 });
```

Work around is:

```
const wrappedPayload = { a: payload };
expect(wrappedPayload).to.nested.include({ 'a[0].id': 0, 'a[1].id': 1 });
```

This works, but I don't like having to wrap it. Very much still open to solutions. Is this a bug I should report to chai team?